# Android GPS service

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

I have a working app that works in activity - it calls GPS data from the phone receiver and sends it to my php site filtering the last location in a thread from sqlite it looks like this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(indikator != 0)
                {
                    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from lokacije", null);
                c.moveToLast();

                try{
                    w.loadUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lokacija")));
                    db.execSQL("delete from lokacije where id <"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }


                }
                indikator=1;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 90000);

            }
        };


    //b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



             if(b.getText().equals("SLOBODAN"))
             {


                 b.setText("ZAUZET");
                 b.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
             }
             else
             {

                 b.setText("SLOBODAN");
                 b.setTextColor(Color.RED);

             }
        }
    });
    //deo koji naknadno ubacujem za kriterijum
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);



    //kraj dela koji sam naknadno ubacio

final   LocationManager m=(LocationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno
String locationprovider =m.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
//deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno kraj


        LocationListener l=new LocationListener() {


                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

                    String url=new String();
                    String zauzetost=new String();
                    zauzetost=b.getText().toString();

                    String format="MM/dd/yyyy";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);
                    String date= sdf.format(new Date());


                t.setToNow();   

                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                String longitude=new String();
                String latitude=new String();
                String speed=new String();

                if((int)arg0.getSpeed()==0)
                {
                    speed="0";
                }
                else
                {
                speed=""+(((int)arg0.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
                }
                longitude=""+  arg0.getLongitude();
                latitude=""+ arg0.getLatitude();
                ed1.setText(longitude);
                ed2.setText(latitude);
                ed3.setText(speed);
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();



                url="http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id="+mojsadrzaj+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&brzina="+speed+"&vreme="+cal.getTime()+"&datum="+date+"&zauzetost="+zauzetost;    

                db.execSQL("insert into lokacije (lokacija) values ('"+url+"');");


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            };


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //pozivanje threada
             runnable.run();
            //pozivanje threada
            m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 60000, 0, l);

    //      zamenio sam m.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 0, l); sa m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 120000, 0, l);
        }
```

Now what I want to do is put it all in a service so that it works in the background .
Should I put my code in `onCreate()` or in `onStart()` method of `Service` since I also use a handler and an another thread . When I call a web site now with URL or HttpClient since i cannot use `WebView` as in `Activity` it gives my mistakes in my logcat like this:

```
  02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=2
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.example.serviceswithactivity.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:127)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-12 22:24:32.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I call a gps location from a service so that i do not get 10-15 points but only one? I did it in Activity by putting the data in a sqlite database and later on taking the last row in a thread and deleting the other rows and so on in a circle. Is there a better way to call a gps location and send it to web site in the background?

This is my entire `Service`:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public int indikator=0;
public String mojsadrzaj=new String();
public String pib=new String();
public String username=new String();
public String password=new String();
public Cursor c;
public Cursor d;
 URL myURL;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();

Toast.makeText(this,"Service created ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("TruckMe", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("create table if not exists lokacije (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, lokacija VARCHAR(600));");

//regulisanje podataka za logovanje samo prvi put


String idvozaca=new String();
db.execSQL("create table if not exists vozac (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, idvozaca VARCHAR(15));");
d=db.rawQuery("select idvozaca from vozac", null);

//db.execSQL("delete from vozac;");

if(d.getCount() > 0)
{
    d.moveToLast();
    idvozaca=d.getString(d.getColumnIndex("idvozaca"));
    mojsadrzaj=idvozaca;
    Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, "Id vozaca je : " + mojsadrzaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    t.show();

}
else
{
    //ubacivanje forme za dijalog




            //unos vozacid u bazu 
            db.execSQL("insert into vozac (idvozaca) values ('"+mojsadrzaj+"');");
            //unos vozacid u bazu

            //String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here
            Toast t=Toast.makeText(this, "Aplikacija je aktivirana sa kodom : "+mojsadrzaj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            t.show();


        }





//regulisanje podataka za logovanje samo prvi put

final Time t=new Time();



 //deo za thread

 final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(indikator != 0)
            {

               //w.loadUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lokacija")));

                    final SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("TruckMe", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    c=db.rawQuery("select * from lokacije", null);
                    c.moveToLast();

                    try {
                        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                        URI website=new URI(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                        Log.e("Message", website.toString());
                        HttpGet request=new HttpGet();
                        request.setURI(website);
                        try {
                            client.execute(request);
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    /*
                    URL url = null;
                    try {
                        url = new URL(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    URLConnection urlConnection = null;
                    try {
                        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        urlConnection.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    */
                    /*
                    try {
                        myURL = new URL(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    URLConnection myURLConnection = null;
                    try {
                        myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        myURLConnection.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                  */


                db.execSQL("delete from lokacije where id <"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));


                    // TODO: handle exception
                  }
            indikator=1;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);

        }
    };


//deo koji naknadno ubacujem za kriterijum
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);



//kraj dela koji sam naknadno ubacio

final   LocationManager m=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno
String locationprovider =m.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
//deo koji sam takodje ubacio naknadno kraj


    LocationListener l=new LocationListener() {


            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

                String url=new String();
                String zauzetost=new String();
                zauzetost="ZAUZET";

                String format="MM/dd/yyyy";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);
                String date= sdf.format(new Date());


            t.setToNow();   


            String longitude=new String();
            String latitude=new String();
            String speed=new String();

            if((int)arg0.getSpeed()==0)
            {
                speed="0";
            }
            else
            {
            speed=""+(((int)arg0.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
            }
            longitude=""+  arg0.getLongitude();
            latitude=""+ arg0.getLatitude();

            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();



            url="http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id="+mojsadrzaj+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&brzina="+speed+"&vreme="+cal.getTime()+"&datum="+date+"&zauzetost="+zauzetost;    
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.execSQL("insert into lokacije (lokacija) values ('"+url+"');");


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //pozivanje threada
         runnable.run();
        //pozivanje threada
        m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 10000, 0, l);

//      zamenio sam m.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 0, l); sa m.requestLocationUpdates(locationprovider, 120000, 0, l);




}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started onstartcommand ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();










   return START_STICKY;

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started onstart...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


}
```

Comment: The problem is not with your GPS code, the problem is that the URL you're trying to load out of your cursor is incorrect. Post the argument of `w.loadUrl`.

Comment: This is what I use in web service instead of w.loadurl

Comment: http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id="+mojsadrzaj+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&brzina="+speed+"&vreme="+cal.getTime()+"&datum="+date+"&zauzetost="+zauzetost these are some variables that printed out and used in browser give good results

Comment: and in Service for loading the url I use HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
       URI website=new URI(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")));
       Log.e("Message", website.toString());
       HttpGet request=new HttpGet();
       request.setURI(website);client.execute(request); with all the try catch in between .

Comment: 02-14 20:35:38.783: W/System.err(1558): java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 168: 
http://www.compensatemeonline.com/truckmeonline/TruckMeOnline/UnosLokacijaSaTelefona.php?id=1&longitude=20.279951666666665&latitude=44.96613333333333
&brzina=0&vreme=Thu Feb 14 20:35:38 GMT 2013&datum=02/14/2013&zauzetost=ZAUZET
This is my URI...

Comment: 'The problem is not with your GPS code, the problem is that the URL you're trying to load out of your cursor is incorrect. Post the argument of w.loadUrl. – hwrdprkns'-You were right for the argument I had some extra space signs in the URL adress!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you were able to get that working! I'll post my comment as an answer for any future users who come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your GPS code, the problem is that the URL you're trying to load out of your cursor is incorrect.

I would recheck that the argument of `w.loadUrl` is correct.

Comment: yes it is so, I used URL to load the page and I had some extra space signs